# finding content of <span> with Beautifulsoup in Python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to find how many times a newspaper article has been shared on Facebook with Beautifulsoup.

Here's the page: https://www.lemonde.fr/international/article/2018/06/10/isole-trump-est-parvenu-a-imposer-son-agenda-au-cours-d-un-g7-tendu_5312382_3210.html

and here's what the html looks like:

```
<div class="fixed-header fixed-header-show">
    <div class="fixed-header-content">
        <a class="fixed-header-logo" href="/"></a>
        <div class="fixed-header-title">Isolé, Trump est parvenu à imposer son agenda au cours d’un G7 explosif</div>
        <div class="fixed-header-sharing-buttons">
            <div data-sharewith="facebook" data-xiti-label="Partage::Facebook::Isolé, Trump est parvenu à imposer son agenda au cours d’un G7 explosif::header">Partager<span class="fixed-header-facebook-likes-counter"> (142)</span></div>
            <div data-sharewith="twitter" data-xiti-label="Partage::Twitter::Isolé, Trump est parvenu à imposer son agenda au cours d’un G7 explosif::header">Tweeter</div>
            <div data-sharewith="google-plus" data-xiti-label="Partage::Google+::Isolé, Trump est parvenu à imposer son agenda au cours d’un G7 explosif::header"></div>
            <div data-sharewith="linkedin" data-xiti-label="Partage::Linkedin::Isolé, Trump est parvenu à imposer son agenda au cours d’un G7 explosif::header"></div>
            <div data-sharewith="pinterest" data-xiti-label="Partage::Pinterest::Isolé, Trump est parvenu à imposer son agenda au cours d’un G7 explosif::header"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here's how I'm retrieving the page source as a string:

```
    try:
        req = Request(url, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
        response = urlopen(req,timeout=20)
    except:
        timeOut = True
        print(url,'timed out')

    if timeOut:
        return "timeOut",[]

    if 'text/html' in response.getheader('Content-Type') and not timeOut:
        htmlBytes = response.read()
        htmlString = htmlBytes.decode("utf-8")
        self.feed(htmlString)
        return htmlString, self.links
    else:
        return "",[]
```

I'm looking for the " (142)" part (this may have changed on the live webpage when you'll look at it), under:

```
<span class="fixed-header-facebook-likes-counter"> (142)</span>
```

Here's how I'm attempting to do it:

```
shares = BeautifulSoup(data, "lxml").find("span", {"class": "fixed-header-facebook-likes-counter"}).text
```

But it return an empty string (and, interestingly, not "None" as when Beautifulsoup doesn't find anything). What am I missing here?

Comment: How are you retrieving the page source? `requests`?

Comment: Yes, I'm updating to clearly explain how! :)

Comment: I dropped the `'lxml'` and for me it is returning the right string.

Comment: `BeautifulSoup(html).find("span", {"class": "fixed-header-facebook-likes-counter"}).text`

Comment: Hmm, Beautifulsoup sends a warning, saying it needs a specific parser, and uses "lxml" as default. So I get the same (none)result, unfortunately

Comment: I tried that as well and got the same thing. I tried using "html.parser" instead of lxml and it returns the span tag correctly, but not the `(142)` content. Do you have to use requests for this or can you use something like Selenium? I was able to get the value you were looking for using that.

Comment: Thanks! I've never used Selenium, and all my other calls use Request in my project, so I'd rather only use it. If possible... Maybe another parser would work better?

Comment: The value is dynamically generated and is not available in the page source. So, you can either use Selenium, or track down if any AJAX request is populating the data using the dev tools and directly access the data from that AJAX request using `requests`.

Comment: Directly requesting the Ajax part worked, thanks!